# TextViewer bookmarks

Tags: android, uitextview

Is there a way I can have a bookmark inside a textviewer?
For example, if I have a textviewer with a long html text in it, I would like to scroll to a certain location\bookmark. Not to a certain % but to a certain line\word.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

well, one option will be to use the webviewer, them you can bind android ui elements with javascript functions

Regards

Comment: No can do... Can I do the same on a textviewer?